# RouterActiveLink doesn't work with routerLink in ng-template

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, ng-template

I've created a new app in "Angular 2" with three components:

- AppComponent
- Test1Component
- Test2Component

There is only one module (*AppModule*) that bootstraps AppComponent, declares AppComponent, Test1Component and Test2Component, and imports 
`RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)`.

This is **appRoutes**:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
},
  {
      path: 'test1',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      component: Test1Component
  },
  {
      path: 'test2',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      component: Test2Component
  }
];
```

This is **app.component.html**:

```
<h1>Test routerLinkActive</h1>
<ul>
  <li routerLinkActive="active">
      <a routerLink="/test1">Link 1</a>       
  </li>
  <li routerLinkActive="active">
      <a routerLink="/test2">Link 2</a>          
  </li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

In **app.component.css** there is:

```
.active>a{
    background: red;
}
```

It works well and when i click the links in the ul, angular loads the right component, shows its content (simple html text: "component works") and it add red background to clicked link.

Now, if i put the  element in a tag  and i reference it in a *ngIf, the components Test1 and Test2 are loaded on link click but the background doesn't added.

Broken version:

```
<h1>Test routerLinkActive</h1>
<ng-template #tpl1>
    <a routerLink="/test1">Link 1</a>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #tpl2>
    <a routerLink="/test2">Link 2</a>
</ng-template>
<ul>
  <li routerLinkActive="active">     
    <div *ngIf="1===1;then tpl1 else tpl1"></div>
  </li>
  <li routerLinkActive="active">      
      <div *ngIf="1===1;then tpl2 else tpl2"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Why?

PS: the condition in the *ngIf is only for example

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use *ngIf and routerLink at li  tag

Like

`<li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="" routerLink="/pages/page">
                <a>tab name</a>
 </li>`